# Word2Vec Dimensionality Causing Problems for KMeans

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, k-means, numpy-ndarray

I have a list `sentences` with 1000 strings that I want to cluster using KMeans. Like so:

```
sentences = [
    ['I', 'received', 'an', 'email']
    ['How', 'do', 'I', 'know', 'it', 'is', 'real?'], 
    ['Ladies', 'and', 'Gentlemen'] 
]
```

I am using word2vec to remove stop words and preprocess the input.

I am running word2vec like so: `m = Word2Vec(sentences, size=50, window=6, min_count=1, sg=1)`

Afterwards, I defined a vectorizer which averages all the word float vectors that were generated by word2vec.

```
def vectorizer(sentence, m):
    vec = []
    numw = 0
    for w in sentence:
        try:
            if numw == 0:
                vec = m[w]
            else:
                vec = np.add(vec, m[w])
            numw+=1
        except:
            pass

    return np.asarray(vec) / numw
```

Finally, I pass the whole input through this vectorizer:

```
def vectorize(sentences, m):
    l = []
    for i in sentences:
        l.append(vectorizer(i, m))

    return np.array(l)
```

Then I call the vectorizer method like so: `X = vectorize(sentences, m)`

When I do `X.shape`, the output is: [1000, 50]. Since the size passed in word2vec is 50. And I have 1000 records.

However, when I change the size to 100 for word2vec, then `X.shape` is just [1000,].

Any idea why this is happening and how to resolve it?

It is causing me issues with KMeans because I am getting this error when I pass it:
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: What does `print(X)`return (for size=100)?

Comment: @DavidM. it's just [1000, ]. Printing X is just a list of vectors of size 100

Comment: A _list_ of vectors is actually a _numpy array_ of vectors according to your code. A shape of [1000,] means that at least one of your 1000 vectors does not have a length of 100 - I would find out which one, and why.